# java: Method cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java

I am trying to use the `.getClass()` method in java to mimic the `getattr` method of python to find a method with the same name as a input string "methodName", but I am getting an error saying

> Method cannot be resolved as a type

Here is the code:

```
Method func = exampleObject.getClass().getMethod("methodName", Object[].class);
func.invoke(exampleObject, args);
```

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about the error you're getting? I'm not super well versed in reflection...

Comment: Show the whole code, you messed something outside this snippet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you forget the import for "Method"?

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
```